Unpivot table but with multiple related columns (list.zip()?)
I'm not sure the best way to explain my question but it's related to unpivoting columns in powerbi.
Currently I have this table where I'm unpivoting from Column C (1st date column) onwards and that's all fine. (The values in the dates refer to "Allocated space" - this will be relevant shortly).

I don't want to just have allocated space over time though I also want another date column for each date for used space eg like this:

So each date has an allocated space and a used space per object and I need to unpivot those but so I have date columns and then a value for used and a value for allocated space.
Does anyone know if this is possible? In my research I came across list.zip() as M code, is that something I would need here?
The only way I can currently think of doing it is with two separate tables, one that does used space and another that does allocated space? But I'm sure there's a better method?
Thank you.

I think I've found an answer via this youtube video:
https://youtu.be/4lVNS83ivsA?si=_pRkRnDS1VREbN_s

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
